# Shuffle items in a Collection object

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a Collection object of unique names. How to i shuffle the items in this collection so that the order of items change every time i work with it. Below is the part of code  for creating the Collection.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If ws1.Cells(i, 3).value < 20 Then
            If uniqueNames.Count = 0 Then
                uniqueNames.Add ws1.Cells(i, 2).value, CStr(ws1.Cells(i, 2).value)
            Else
                On Error Resume Next
                uniqueNames.Add ws1.Cells(i, 2).value, CStr(ws1.Cells(i, 2).value)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShuffleArray.aspx is for arrays but could easily be adapted for a collection.

Comment: Following the code give in the above link, i am getting an 'Object Required' error when i try to assign a value to collection item like this uniqueNames.Item(i) = uniqueNames.Item(j). Here unqueNames is Collection object.

Comment: You need to use Set when assigning object-type variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are better ways of doing this but this is how I would do it:

```
Function shuffledCollection(ByVal col As Collection) As Collection
    Set shuffledCollection = New Collection
    Do While col.Count > 0
        Dim randomIndex As Integer
        randomIndex = Int(Rnd() * col.Count) + 1
        shuffledCollection.Add col(randomIndex)
        col.Remove randomIndex
    Loop
End Function
```

To shuffle your collection, you can do:

```
uniqueNames = shuffledCollection(uniqueNames)
```