# How to make a random numbers in a list with excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of numbers, for example: `{ 3, 5, 8, 11 }`, how to show only these 4 numbers randomly using excel vba each time running the code?

Thank you!

I already try using excel formulas (`RAND`, `RANDBETWEEN`) but the results are not what I need.

Comment: You could put the numbers in a collection, shuffle it and loop through the shuffled items. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75399066/9852011

Comment: Why weren't the results you got using formulas acceptable? What formulas did you try?

Comment: To @andrewb: I will try that now

Comment: @JosWoolley: I tried RAND, RANDBETWEEN but the results just show value between to numbers, not between list of numbers.

Comment: Did you try something like `=SORTBY(A1:A4,RANDARRAY(ROWS(A1:A4)))`, where `A1:A4` contains your four numbers? Or `=@SORTBY(A1:A4,RANDARRAY(ROWS(A1:A4)))` if you just want a single random result from those four numbers.

Comment: @JosWoolley: Thank you for your instruction, I've tried, it worked also!

Answer (score 2):

Try a formula:

`=@SORTBY(A1:A4,RANDARRAY(ROWS(A1:A4)))`